# createobject( shell.application ) raises exception "library not registered"

Tags: windows, dll, dllregistration

this line

```
createobject( shell.application )
```

raises this exception **"library not registered"** on a Win7 PC

It seems that a `dll` is missing or is not registered.

1°) Which `dll` is not registered ?
2°) How can I solve this issue ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: It is an error message about a *type library* not being registered.  COM error 0x8002801D.  It cannot be raised by this statement, maybe another one that actually uses the returned object.  Improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

As the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/bb774063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page shows its Shell32.dll
You can register dll's via regsvr32 thedll.dll via cmd.exe

Comment: Ok. How is it possible that shell32.dll could not be registered on a system ?

Comment: Try looking for that dll in your windows/system32 folder
If you can find that dll try to manually add that dll to your project and/or register it via regsvr32

Comment: Additionally look over [there](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/shell-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm)